# Trouble with OpenID login within iframe in Safari

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've had users using my site http://dealclippings.com report that they aren't able to login.  I'm struggling to determine the cause and was wondering if anyone could help me debug the problem.

Comment: Could be the Safari iframe caching bug. Try generating a unique ID for your iframe. See http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=150101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that as a security measure in OpenID, you can't authenticate in an iframe.  It prevents the web site from maliciously catching your password or tricking you in other ways.

Good to know!

Comment: Can you confirm that this is specified behavior? Firefox and Chrome permit OpenID authentication inside an iframe.